# Using local variable of ngFor in child elements

Tags: typescript, angular, ngfor

I want to display a property of the local variable `theme` like `theme.name`.

This is how my `*ngFor` looks like

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#theme of themes">
      <span>theme.name</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to use `{{theme.name}}` as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. If `theme` has a `name` property `{{theme.name}}` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
{{theme.name}}
```

doesn't work, then

```
{{theme?.name}}
```

probably will